# Pandas - How to update non-numeric values to numeric and sum them up? Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DF like this:

| Student | Age | Grades |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 23 | A B C |
| Mark | 22 | B B C |
| Ian | 24 | A B A |

As you can see grades are in non-numeric format, I would like to:

- map each letter from column "grades" to numeric values (A=1, B=2, C=3)
- sum up updated values (e.g. A B C = 1,2,3 = 6)
- create a new column which would hold summed data

Example of wanted output:

| Student | Age | Grades | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 23 | A B C | 6 |
| Mark | 22 | B B C | 7 |
| Ian | 24 | A B A | 4 |

How to do this with Pandas?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a function in which you map the non-numerical grades to a numerical one.

```
def grades_to_num(grades):
    grades_dict = {"A":1, "B":2, "C":3}
    numgrades = [grades_dict[grade] for grade in grades.split()]
    return sum(numgrades)
```

You can then apply the function to your df to create a new column with the numerical sum.

```
df["Sum"] = df["Grades"].apply(grades_to_num)
```

Comment: Thanks, Mitchel, perfect. Quick and efficient, I like the function so it can be used again when needed for similar actions.

Comment: you can use map and replace the A,B,C values in the dataframe then work with only numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dictionary of map of grades to number. Then split `Grades` column by space and convert each of the grades to number using `map` and the dictionary (`list(map(lambda x: grade_num[x], x))`) and sum the obtained values.

```
grade_num = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
df['Sum'] = (df['Grades'].str.split(' ')
             .apply(lambda x: np.sum(list(map(lambda x: grade_num[x], x)))))

df

   Student  Age Grades  Sum
0   Joe     23  A B C   6
1   Mark    22  B B C   7
2   Ian     24  A B A   4
```

Comment: Thanks @ggaurav , I went with the other solution, but your's rather similar. Also nice and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a sample example where I have created a dataframe (without the column names) and updated the values by creating a copy of the dataframe and introducing a new column (3) as the sum. The code example is written just using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
grades = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
df = pd.DataFrame([['Joe', 23, 'A B C'], ['Mark', 22, 'B B C']])
new_df = df.copy()
new_df[3] = 0

for i, r in new_df.iterrows():
    grade_list = r[2].split(" ")
    s = 0
    for g in grade_list:
        s  += grades[g]
    new_df.loc[i, 3] = s
```